# compiling vim with python support

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to compile Vim 7.2 with Python 2.5.1 support, but I'm having some trouble.

1. I run configure which seems like it is working as expected

   ```
   ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --prefix=/home/username/vimpy
   ```

   I can see that changes to `--with-features` works as I expect (the final compiled version has new features), and it sets up Python correctly

   checking for python... (cached) //python/2.5/bin/python
   checking Python version... (cached) 2.5
   checking Python is 1.4 or better... yep
   checking Python's install prefix... (cached) //python/2.5
   checking Python's execution prefix... (cached) //python/2.5(cached)
   checking Python's configuration directory... (cached) //python/2.5/lib/python2.5/config/
2. Then I run `make`, but I don't even see it trying to compile anything Python like.

   ```
   CC="gcc -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -I/usr/X11R6/include       " srcdir=. sh ./osdef.sh
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/buffer.o buffer.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/charset.o charset.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/diff.o diff.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/digraph.o digraph.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/edit.o edit.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/eval.o eval.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/ex_cmds.o ex_cmds.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/ex_cmds2.o ex_cmds2.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/ex_docmd.o ex_docmd.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/ex_eval.o ex_eval.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/ex_getln.o ex_getln.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/fileio.o fileio.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/fold.o fold.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/getchar.o getchar.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/hardcopy.o hardcopy.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/hashtab.o hashtab.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/if_cscope.o if_cscope.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o if_xcmdsrv.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/main.o main.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/mark.o mark.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/memfile.o memfile.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/memline.o memline.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/menu.o menu.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/message.o message.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/misc1.o misc1.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/misc2.o misc2.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/move.o move.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/mbyte.o mbyte.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/normal.o normal.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/ops.o ops.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/option.o option.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/os_unix.o os_unix.c
   creating auto/pathdef.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/pathdef.o auto/pathdef.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/popupmnu.o popupmnu.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/quickfix.o quickfix.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/regexp.o regexp.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/screen.o screen.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/search.o search.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/spell.o spell.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/syntax.o syntax.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/tag.o tag.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/term.o term.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/ui.o ui.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/undo.o undo.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/window.o window.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/gui.o gui.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/gui_gtk.o gui_gtk.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/gui_gtk_x11.o gui_gtk_x11.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/pty.o pty.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/gui_gtk_f.o gui_gtk_f.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/gui_beval.o gui_beval.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/netbeans.o netbeans.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        version.c -o objects/version.o
   gcc  -L/usr/X11R6/lib64   -L/usr/local/lib  -o vim objects/buffer.o objects/charset.o objects/diff.o objects/digraph.o objects/edit.o objects/eval.o objects/ex_cmds.o objects/ex_cmds2.o objects/ex_docmd.o objects/ex_eval.o objects/ex_getln.o objects/fileio.o objects/fold.o objects/getchar.o objects/hardcopy.o objects/hashtab.o  objects/if_cscope.o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o objects/main.o objects/mark.o objects/memfile.o objects/memline.o objects/menu.o objects/message.o objects/misc1.o objects/misc2.o objects/move.o objects/mbyte.o objects/normal.o objects/ops.o objects/option.o objects/os_unix.o objects/pathdef.o objects/popupmnu.o objects/quickfix.o objects/regexp.o objects/screen.o objects/search.o objects/spell.o objects/syntax.o  objects/tag.o objects/term.o objects/ui.o objects/undo.o objects/window.o objects/gui.o objects/gui_gtk.o objects/gui_gtk_x11.o objects/pty.o objects/gui_gtk_f.o objects/gui_beval.o        objects/netbeans.o  objects/version.o   -Wl,--export-dynamic -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lpangoxft-1.0 -lpangox-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -ldl -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -lncurses -lnsl  -ldl
   link.sh: OK, linking works, let's try removing a few libraries.
   link.sh: See auto/link.log for details.
   link.sh: Trying to remove the SM library...
   link.sh: We don't need the SM library!
   link.sh: Trying to remove the SM library...
   link.sh: We don't need the SM library!
   link.sh: Trying to remove the ICE library...
   link.sh: We don't need the ICE library!
   link.sh: Trying to remove the ICE library...
   link.sh: We don't need the ICE library!
   link.sh: Trying to remove the nsl library...
   link.sh: We don't need the nsl library!
   link.sh: Trying to remove the Xt library...
   link.sh: We DO need the Xt library.
   link.sh: Trying to remove the Xpm library...
   link.sh: We don't need the Xpm library!
   link.sh: Trying to remove the X11 library...
   link.sh: We don't need the X11 library!
   link.sh: Trying to remove the Xdmcp library...
   link.sh: We don't need the Xdmcp library!
   link.sh: Trying to remove the dl library...
   link.sh: We don't need the dl library!
   link.sh: Trying to remove the dl library...
   link.sh: We don't need the dl library!
   link.sh: Trying to remove the m library...
   link.sh: We don't need the m library!

   creating auto/pathdef.c
   gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include     -g -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include        -o objects/pathdef.o auto/pathdef.c
   link.sh: Using auto/link.sed file to remove a few libraries
     gcc  -L/usr/X11R6/lib64   -L/usr/local/lib  -o vim objects/buffer.o objects/charset.o objects/diff.o objects/digraph.o objects/edit.o objects/eval.o objects/ex_cmds.o objects/ex_cmds2.o objects/ex_docmd.o objects/ex_eval.o objects/ex_getln.o objects/fileio.o objects/fold.o objects/getchar.o objects/hardcopy.o objects/hashtab.o  objects/if_cscope.o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o objects/main.o objects/mark.o objects/memfile.o objects/memline.o objects/menu.o objects/message.o objects/misc1.o objects/misc2.o objects/move.o objects/mbyte.o objects/normal.o objects/ops.o objects/option.o objects/os_unix.o objects/pathdef.o objects/popupmnu.o objects/quickfix.o objects/regexp.o objects/screen.o objects/search.o objects/spell.o objects/syntax.o  objects/tag.o objects/term.o objects/ui.o objects/undo.o objects/window.o objects/gui.o objects/gui_gtk.o objects/gui_gtk_x11.o objects/pty.o objects/gui_gtk_f.o objects/gui_beval.o        objects/netbeans.o  objects/version.o   -Wl,--export-dynamic -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangoxft-1.0 -lpangox-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lXt -lm -lncurses
   link.sh: Linked fine with a few libraries removed
   cd xxd; CC="gcc" CFLAGS=" -g -O2" \
           make -f Makefile
   ```
3. `make install` works fine
4. Test the Python support

   ```
   > :ver shows -python 
   > and :python print 'hello' says 'Sorry, the command is not available in this version'
   ```

What am I missing? It's driving me a little crazy.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I've also had "... and link flags for Python are sane... no: PYTHON DISABLED"

On Ubuntu 10.04 you have to install '**python2.6-dev**'. The flags for ./configure are:

```
--enable-pythoninterp

--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.6/config
```

Make sure you got a path to directory, which contains '**config.c**' file. Also no '**/**' at the end of the path! That caused me problems.

Comment: Also you can get error messages through load caching process because you load old caches. It can helps 'rm auto/config.cache'.

Comment: `/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu` on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @alexche8 your comment really helped me out. it's odd that configure gives me the same cache even after some of the options are changed : (

Comment: For what it's worth: I successfully built Vim with Python2.7 support without the line `--with-python-config-dir=...`. I cannot locate the config directory even though I had `python-dev` installed.

Comment: `$(python3.x-config --configdir)` directly in the command instead of a path to get the path automatically (replace the `x` with a number so it's a valid version of python; `python3.8-config` for me)

Answer (score 9):

You could try adding the option `--with-python-config-dir=/your/python/config/dir`

The path should point to the location of the file config.c of your Python installation.

Answer (score 7):

Yea! I figured it out, so I'm writing up a quick how-to in case others run into the same issue:

1. I didn't notice an important message in the configure output:

   ```
   checking if compile and link flags for Python are sane... no: PYTHON DISABLED
   ```
2. The log file had more info located in src/auto/config.log:

   ```
   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible <mypydist>/2.5/lib/python2.5/config//libpython2.5.a when searching for -lpython2.5
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.5
   ```
3. I found an old thread that said you can override the gcc call by setting:

   ```
   export vi_cv_path_python_plibs="-L/<mypydist>/2.5/lib/python2.5/config/ ..."
   excluding the -lpython2.5
   ```

Now it compiles.

Comment: For python 3, you can use `vi_cv_path_python3_plibs=$(python3-config --ldflags)`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem with Python2.7 and openSUSE 11.4/64. Here's a technique that worked for me:

```
zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/editors/openSUSE_11.4 editors
zypper in vim-enhanced
zypper in vim-enhanced-7.3-112.1.x86_64
```

vim-enhanced on openSUSE is compiled with +python. vim-enhanced from the standard openSUSE repo crashed when trying :python print 'hello' in vim. The compiled version from the editors repo worked for me without crashing.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** 2019: `vim8.2` `python3` for Ubuntu: This is like `texlive-full` you will not have any problem after that.

**Note:** that you **cannot** get both `python3/dyn` and `ptyhon2/dyn`

```sh
./configure \
            --with-features=huge \
            --prefix=/usr/local \
            --disable-netbeans \
            --enable-gui=auto \
            \
            --enable-cscope \
            --enable-fail-if-missing \
            --enable-largefile \
            --enable-luainterp \
            --enable-multibyte \
            \
            --enable-perlinterp=dynamic \
            --enable-python3interp=dynamic \
            --with-python3-config-dir=$(python3-config --configdir) \
            --enable-rubyinterp=dynamic \
            --with-ruby-command=$(which ruby) \
            --with-luajit \
            \
            --with-compiledby="stackoverflow.com/questions/3373914" \
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where i did a non-global python install. I had to set `--with-python3-command=` to the path of my python binary

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an easy way to get ConqueTerm with vim. So I could get a bash terminal in a split screen with vim ala emacs.

```
opensuse 11.4 | i586| 32bit
```

from googling around it would seem the only quick fix way is to install the

vim-enhanced 7.3.456 version of vim, I had come across another link download referring to the 7.3.456 rpm. It had dependency issues so I was reluctant. However sometime later...

I added the above repository and zyperred vim-enhanced selecting option 1 to fix dependencies. It complains about nokeys on install which I don't like but I'm new to OpenSuse and don't know how bad this is to ignore this.

Anyhow this version of vim is the only one I have found which works and loads ConqueTerm correctly giving me my bash terminal inside vim.

If your looking for ConqueTerm with vim on OpenSuse 11.4 via a package. Find a repository to insatll vim-enhanced version 7.3.456 as this seems to work with ConqueTerm and is python enabled.