# Fix native Cygwin Vim Python support

Tags: python, vim, plugins, cygwin

After installing the python-mode plugin for Vim on my Linux machine, I am getting the following error message on my Windows machine with Cygwin using the same .vim folder:

```
pymode.vim required vim compiled with +python.
```

So basically I need to compile Vim by my own with Python support, like explained in the question [compiling vim with python support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373914/compiling-vim-with-python-support)?

This would be quite annoying, does someone know alternatives? After all Windows Vim seems to support Python.

Comment: Did you build your own Vim for Cygwin? If you didn't explicitely built it with python you'll have to do another build. Vim for Windows supports Python because of ease of use concerns but it looks like Cygwin is not a priority for the Vim team.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/382430/building-vim-with-python-support-in-cygwin

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am afraid, that is the only way to fix it. Unpleasant, but at least doable with only a few lines:

```
$ hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
$ cd vim/src
$ ./configure \
--enable-multibyte \
--without-x \
--enable-gui=no \
--enable-pythoninterp

$ make
$ make install
$ ln -sf /usr/local/bin/vim.exe /usr/bin/vim
```

Make sure you have installed `libncurses-devel` for  Cygwin beforehand.

Comment: Vim is now on github so you can no use `git clone git@github.com:b4winckler/vim.git` if you don't have mercurial installed