# Getting python support in vim

Tags: python, vim

After reading [short guide](https://github.com/skyeagle/vim-rails-bootstrap/wiki/Compiling-vim-with-ruby,-python-and-multibyte-support)  and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373914/compiling-vim-with-python-support) I figure out how to configure Vim:

```
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-rubyinterp --enable-pythoninterp 
--enable-perlinterp --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr 
--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

And now *make && sudo make install*. [Here](http://pastebin.com/SnMPdKsA) is the log of *./configure* command.
But the problem is here that after this build I didn't get python support. Below I paste two lines of the list of a features what I see when launch Vim and typing ":version"

```
+cindent -ebcdic +jumplist -mouse_jsbterm -python -tag_any_white +windows 
+clientserver -emacs_tags -keymap -mouse_netterm -python3
```

"-" sign means the disabled features, to my regret the python one of them. Am I miss something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you only show the output for python3 but you configured for python (2.7). Show the output for `vim --version | grep python`. You are looking for a `+python` or `-python` (no 3)

Comment: `+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +viminfo
-cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eg. for vim73:

```
./configure --enable-pythoninterp | grep python
checking --enable-pythoninterp argument... yes
checking for python... (cached) /usr/bin/python
(cached) checking Python's configuration directory... (cached) /usr/lib/python2.6/config
checking --enable-python3interp argument... no
```

:version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul 17 2013 00:21:48)
+python -python3
-L/usr/local/lib -o vim    -lncurses -L/usr/lib/python2.6/config -lpython2.6 -lpthread 
-ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Are you sure you run just your compiled vim version? Likely you run old code from /usr/bin/vim, try to reload bash to run from /usr/local/bin/vim.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I don't know why, but `sudo make uninstall` doesn't worked correctly, now I remove vim file by myself and install again -- it works! Thank you very much!