# Compile vim7.4 source code with python support failed

Tags: python, vim

I have download the source code of vim7.4 and decide to upgrade the vim to 7.4.
However, I can not add python support to it:

```
./configure  --enable-pythoninterp  --enable-rubyinterp --enable-gui=no --without-x --enable-cscope --enable-multibyte --prefix=/usr
```

While checking src/auto/config.log, I found:

```
configure:5592: checking Python's configuration directory
configure:5614: result:·
configure:5620: result: can't find it!
```

Installed python info:

```
dpkg-query -l python
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version                          Description
+++-================================-================================-   ================================================================================
ii  python                           2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                 interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)
```

After invoking *make* in the src dir:

```
./vim --version | grep python
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
```

It seems that it's caused by vim unable to locate the config dir for python. How to fix it?

Thanks for your insights in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [compiling vim with python support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373914/compiling-vim-with-python-support)

Comment: It seems missing `python-dev`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you have the python development packages installed (python-devel or python-dev I think). You can specify the python config directory by passing, to `./configure`, something like:

```
--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib64/python2.7/config
```

To find the config directory (you may need to do `updatedb` first):

```
locate python | grep '/config$'
```

Comment: I have tried to add --with-python-config-dir= /usr/lib/python2.7/config into the ./configuration command flag.   Encounter new problem on *make*:                                       -I/usr/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_HOME='"/usr"' -pthread -fPIE  -o objects/if_python.o if_python.c
if_python.c:58:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [objects/if_python.o] Error 1

Comment: ~  locate python | grep '/config$' 
                                                         /usr/lib/python2.7/config

Comment: do you have the python development package installed? And what is the output of `locate Python.h`

Comment: On Mac OS X, python3 installed by homebrew. I used the command `locate python3 | grep '/config$', but nothing output on terminal. What can I do next? @perreal

Comment: i run `rm src/auto/config.cache && ./configure --enable-pythoninterp=yes --prefix=/data/exec/vim --with-python-command=/data/exec/python2.7/bin/python2.7` and DO NOT forget `rm src/auto/config.cache`, or you will got 'too old' version python hint if you do compile with python2.6 before

Comment: You may need to install python-devel first. 
On CentOS, just ```sudo yum install -y python-devel```

Answer (score 10):

From your error messages you don't have `python-dev` installed

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

this should fix your problem

Comment: +1, this will install the header files for the Python source that Vim needs.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have installed the development packages for python and point towards the appropriate `config` directory.

ex: `./configure --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers give the correct solution i.e adding the cli switch

```
--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config
```

Also it might be a good idea to run

```
make clean distclean
```

For me without cleaning the existing build it wouldn't pickup the new configs