# python 2 support in vim

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim, plugins

I am trying to set up YouCompleteMe, a code-completion plugin for vim.  When I run vim, it gives me this error message: "YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires python 2.x".  I have the correct version of python installed on my ubuntu machine and this confused me.  After some research, I have found that I needed python2 support in *vim*, not just on my system (https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/35).  How can I do this?  I was unable to find a similar answer anywhere.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! I hope you have a great time here.

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using? How did you install vim?

Comment: After a discussion with the developer of YCM, he made it clear he refuses to document this issue in the README. I ran into the exact same issue, and if you search on the tool's issue tracker or online with Google, there are quite a few cases of people reporting this common problem. Yet, as, according to Val, the YCM server's inability to run under Python 3 is the fault of ("a bug in", sic) Vim and Python, he refuses to document the requirement of needing Python 2 to use his tool. https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1140#issuecomment-53972602

Comment: How are people getting auto-completion on Vim on Ubuntu 16.04? None of the answers below solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `aptitude install vim-nox` or `aptitude install vim-gnome` if you want the GUI. `vim-python` is a virtual package provided by either of these.

By default, Ubuntu has `vim-tiny` installed, which has a bunch of the options switched off.

Comment: I tried installing both of those packages, but I am still receiving the same error message...  The machine that I am using is just a terminal, and it has no gui, if that helps.

Comment: I have removed it, but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Hmm, this works for me on Ubuntu. Can you open Vim and do `:python print "Hello World"`?

Comment: You probably need the "dev" python package.

Comment: None of the proposed solutions work! I am running Ubuntu and Archlinux. Arch has vim-python packages and installing those solved the problem, while on Ubuntu nothing helps. I have identical .vimrc and plugins on both machines.

Comment: I needed to use the `vim-gnome-py2` package otherwise the python 3 feature is used by default, which YCM didn't work with

Answer (score 4):

It means your need python2 support in vim, not just in your system. To test whether your vim support python, execute the following command:

> vim --version | grep python

If you find "+python" in the output your vim support python2, "-python" means your vim don't support python2, you need recompile vim with python flag via the vim source.

On windows platform try the following command:

> nmake -f Make_mvc.mak FEATURES=huge PYTHON=D:\Python27 PYTHON_VER=27 GUI=yes IME=yes

on Linux platform try the folowing command:

> ./configure --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.6/config
>   make
>   make install

more details see:

[compiling vim with python support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373914/)

https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/35

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the YouCompleteMe fails if both python3 and python2 support are compiled into Vim. Both version can't be used so the first one touched will prevent the other one from working.