# linux , vim: upgrade vim to have python support

Tags: python, linux, vim

I am starting to try to set up vim so i can use it as an IDE for developing python.
At the first step, I realised my version of vim doesn't have python support.
I browse few questions on the topic on SO, and mot recommend installing another version of vim that is `aptitude install vim-nox` (for instance: [python 2 support in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601729/python-2-support-in-vim)). My question is: Do I need to uninstall my current version of vim before I do so?

Sorry for the noob question, I just dont want to create an horrible mess on the first step...

Subsidiary question: I mostly use python3, but in case I need to work with 2, is there a way to have vim support for both versions, and be able to switch between the 2 of them, like with virtual envs?

Comment: What's wrong with using regular vim and terminal to run python?

Comment: @Mike Tung I am following this tutorial which suggest to get python support:  https://realpython.com/blog/python/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/ . I think it has to do with later installation of syntax highlighting, auto indentation etc.

Comment: What OS/distro are you using? Most versions of vim installed by package managers do usually have Python support compiled in. Are you sure yours doesn't?

Comment: check this out 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/775059/vim-python-support-on-ubuntu-16-04/775073

first uninstall vim then install vim-gtk ( thats what i did to enable clipboard )

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I am using debian , i checked for python support by typing vim --version.

Comment: @Tripurari Shankar Ok so, suys, you confirm that I have to uninstall my current version first? BTW your link doesnt mention uninstalling?

Comment: @jim  i suggested to uninstall current version because some time it may conflict with your old version and when you type vim it may open other one and i also recommend using neovim witch is awesome