# Error "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" shows while compiling vim (Versin>=7.4.399) from Cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin

I've tired to maintenance the latest VIM/GVIM for windows, [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/marslosvimgvim/files/) is my OpenSource project.

However, I found the compile **always failed** by cygwin since the vim version **higher than `v7.4.399`** (including v7.4.399).

**Version less than v7.4.399 can be compiled with the same command successfully!**

Failed Information:

```
obj/ex_docmd.o:ex_docmd.c:(.text+0x45f): undefined reference to `crypt_get_key'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0xbb7): undefined reference to `crypt_works_inplace'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0xbe6): undefined reference to `crypt_encode_alloc'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0xd69): undefined reference to `crypt_encode_inplace'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x69e3): undefined reference to `crypt_free_state'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x6c66): undefined reference to `crypt_free_state'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x6c97): undefined reference to `crypt_free_key'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x716f): undefined reference to `crypt_get_method_nr'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x7177): undefined reference to `crypt_get_header_len'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x8e48): undefined reference to `crypt_works_inplace'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x8e73): undefined reference to `crypt_decode_inplace'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x906d): undefined reference to `crypt_method_nr_from_magic'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x9098): undefined reference to `crypt_set_cm_option'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x90c8): undefined reference to `crypt_create_from_header'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x90df): undefined reference to `crypt_set_cm_option'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x90e7): undefined reference to `crypt_get_header_len'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x9158): undefined reference to `crypt_decode_alloc'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x9e3f): undefined reference to `crypt_append_msg'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x9ed4): undefined reference to `crypt_get_method_nr'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x9edc): undefined reference to `crypt_get_header_len'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0xa5bc): undefined reference to `crypt_get_key'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0xca32): undefined reference to `crypt_free_state'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0xdd15): undefined reference to `crypt_get_method_nr'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0xdd37): undefined reference to `crypt_create_for_writing'
obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0xe2d2): undefined reference to `crypt_append_msg'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/bin/ld: obj/fileio.o: bad reloc address 0x2e8 in section `.rdata'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Make_cyg.mak:603: recipe for target 'vim.exe' failed
make: *** [vim.exe] Error 1
```

The compile command:

```
 make -B -f Make_cyg.mak PYTHON=/cygdrive/c/Marslo/MyProgramFiles/Python27 DYNAMIC_PYTHON=yes PYTHON_VER=27 PYTHON3=/cygdrive/c/Marslo/MyProgramFiles/Python34 DYNAMIC_PYTHON3=yes PYTHON3_VER=34 FEATURES=huge IME=yes GIME=yes MBYTE=yes CSCOPE=yes USERNAME=Marslo.Jiao USERDOMAIN=China GUI=no
```

I checked the [difference](https://github.com/b4winckler/vim/commit/d99496ef175f9ab0b461d583cf61eb4f10acd6ab) between `v7-4-398` and `v7-4-399`, and found there something updated with **encryption**. Then I added the libs and other stuff about **crypt** in cygwin as below, but the compile still CANNOT work....
[image: crypt]

What should I do can compile the higher version vim ?

---

Environments:

- Cygwin version: Latest `setup-x86_64.exe`, `mintty 1.2-beta1 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)`

Comment: And by using `CC=gcc CXX=g++` (inspired from [YCM compile](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/684)) still cannot work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried compiling with all the patches that are currently available. I think Bram Moolenaar (Maintainer for vim)  forgot to add some of the files in one of the patches and one of the later one fixes that. If not post to `vim_dev@vim.org`

This was also reported to at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/D8FyRd0EwlE.

Patch 7.4.401 should fix it https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/q0dbl0_9k9U

Comment: Hi @FDinoff, thanks for your comments. As your said, The windows compile **SUCCESSFULLY** by using the higher version (>= 7.4.401). I want to say, is there anything about **CI (Contentious Integration)** and **Code review** for vim? Compile problem is very easy to findout..

Comment: And, [the comments for 7.4.401](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/detail?r=ab71bb81b84e9a1cdf030b172f61d779ccda975c) is pretty cool:`Problem:    Can't build on MS-Windows.
Solution:   Include the new files in all the Makefiles.`

Comment: @Marslo I don't believe vim has anything like Continuous integration. Bram handles all patches himself. I assume he tests the linux parts himself. But he lets other people handle building on other platforms.

Comment: CI isn't a difficult stuff... compile job more simply... I think it's time (about bug for verion 7.4.399) to involve the new process..Only one computer, three virtual machine with three different OS.

Comment: @Marslo I think people have wanted the vim development process to change for a long time. If you think they should add it you can make a suggestion to the vim_dev mailing list.

Comment: that's cool... How can I add in to the vim_dev mailing list? My mail is: marslo.jiao(AT)gmail.com

Comment: @Marslo Read http://www.vim.org/community.php. Then the google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vim_dev

Answer (score 1):

Got this issue again on CentOS 7, Python 2.7.10, 64bit.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373914/compiling-vim-with-python-support/3374948#3374948) answer, this issue has been fixed;

```
export vi_cv_path_python_plibs="-L/<python_config_path> ..."
```

For example in my situation:

```
export vi_cv_path_python_plibs="-L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config ..."
```

Compile command:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.marslo/myprograms/vim74 --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config --with-features=huge --disable-smack --enable-cscope --with-tlib=ncurses --with-compiledby=marslo@china
$ cd src && make first
$ cd .. && make
$ make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable sodium library in ./configure such as :
`./configure -disable-libsodium`