# How to make vim74 compile with python

Tags: python, vim, bundle

I have installed vim74(by downloading the source code) with Neobundle successfully.

```
alias vim='~/vim74/bin/vim'
~/vim74/bin/vim
```

Also I am using anaconda's python. `~/anaconda/bin/python`
But when I try to open an python file, it says

```
jedi-vim requires vim compiled with +python 
PyFlake.vim required vim compiled with +python
```

The jedi-vim and PyFlake.vim plugins are automatically downloaded by Neobundle. What should I do with my vim?

Comment: What `./configure` arguments did you use to compile Vim and why don't you simply use the one provided by your package manager?

Comment: The plugins aren't the issue, you need to compile *vim* with Python support. Something like `./configure ... --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config ...`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5293524/1599111) for example.

Comment: I tried `--with-python-config-dir=/home/allen/anaconda/bin/python/config` and reinstalled vim74. But it does not work.

Comment: And also `--enable-pythoninterp`? Remember to check whether it worked using `:version` in Vim to check for +python or +python/dyn.

Comment: There are python-enabled builds available for every platform ([Mac OS X](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases), [Windows](http://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/), Linux via your package manager). Why do you try to build it manually to begin with?

Comment: @Ben I have tried `--enable-pythoninterp` But when using `:version`,it still says `-python`. What should I do, I am going crazy.

Comment: @romainl I am using anaconda because it contains all necessary libraries that I have to use. Now I want to make my vim74 support the python. I have tried many ways. But it does not work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: "Does not work" means ***nothing.*** Show us the relevant parts of the output of `./configure`.

Comment: Well you need to `make clean` and `make distclean` before you can reconfigure and rebuild. (I'm sure about the first, less sure about the second).

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your kind answer. I have tried both `make clean` and `make distclean`. But it still says `-python`. I am going crazy. It took me an entire day!

Comment: @wanglan8498 add `--enable-fail-if-missing` to the configure flags. This will cause configure to fail if it can't find python.

Comment: You should look at the output of the configure script. Normally it tells you the result of the checks it does. Capture to a file, there's a lot of output! Then search for python.

Comment: @FDinoff Thanks for your answer. I tried `--enable-fail-if-missing`. But it says `~/anaconda/bin/python/config/Makefile: Not a directory
auto/configure: line 5639: cd: ~/anaconda/bin/python/config: Not a directory`. I don not know where is `Makefile` and where is `config`
Could you give me some ideas?

Comment: @wanglan8498 Lets think for a second. Is `~/anaconda/bin/python` a directory? I think thats an executable. Why? Because it is in the bin directory. bin generally has binaries. Well lets see if we can find a config dir. Running `find ~/anaconda -name config -type d` will list all directories inside `~/anaconda` that are named config. One of them is `~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/config` which looks very very similar to what @ LukasGraf's comment suggested. My guess is you want that path for the config dir. (It also has a Makefile in it)

Comment: @FDinoff Thanks very much for your detailed and kind answer. I installed it successfully.It is beyond my word to express my gratitude to you. You are the hero!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on how to update vim without root access. Especially thanks @FDinoff for his patient instruction. Let me summarize the answer to this question.

Firstly,  `tar xvzf vim-7.4.tar.bz2`

Secondly,`./configure --prefix=~/vim74 --with-features=huge --enable-rubyinterp --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/config --enable-perlinterp --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --enable-luainterp --enable-fail-if-missing`

Lastly, `make`
        `make install`

By the way, I also learnt how to use `find ~/anaconda -name config -type d` in a flexible way.